# Get form field value and add to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

somewhat new to javascript and have run into a problem while running an experiment to help myself learn this stuff.
I have some form fields that I want to access and put their values into an array - seems simple enough, and it works within the console in Chrome but not when I try running the whole thing from within the javascript file.

Here's my javascript:

```
// Create empty array for field names
var fields = [];
// Create empty array for field values
var words = [];


//Add field IDs to array 'fields' - creates ['word-0','word-1','word-2']
for(var i = 0; i < 3; i+= 1){
    var myField = "word-" + i;
    fields.push(myField);
}

//Function to add field values to an array
function getValue(name){
    var fieldValue = document.getElementById(name).value;
     if(fieldValue != ""){
        // If the field has a value, add it to the 'words' array
        words.push(fieldValue);
        return words;
    }else{
        return 'No value in field';
    }
}
```

When I call the function directly in my javascript, I get an error saying Cannot read property 'value' of null on the 'fieldValue' var

```
// Doesn't work
getValue(fields[0]);

// Even this doesn't work
getValue('word-0');
```

However, if I leave the function call out of my script and just run it from the console in chrome it works as expected and doesn't throw any errors.

```
If run from within chrome console, both of these work:
// Works
getValue(fields[0]);

// Works
getValue('word-0');
```

Thanks for any ideas as to why this isn't working.

PS. I'd really like a vanilla JavaScript solution, no jQuery.

Comment: Can you post your html as well?

Comment: Please post the HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are not waiting for the DOM to be ready. By including the script directly in the HTML, the code will be executed immediately. If you put it in the HEAD for example (bad practice, should be put before the closing ), the script will be run before the HTML is parsed. Therefore `document.getElementById(name)` will return null (as the browser does not know about it). And this is why it works when called from the console (the browser knows about the whole page).

To fix this, either wrap your code inside a domReady() callback (preferred solution) or move the  tag at the bottom of your page.

Comment: Thank you, linking to the script at the bottom of the HTML fixed the problem. But both of your solutions did work.